# How can I reduce the frequency of a waveform

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

Is there a circuit which outputs a reduced-frequency of square waveform given at its input while maintaining its duty cycle?

[image]

Comment: For what purpose you need to bring down the frequency but keep duty? It might be easier to modify the original circuit than to add a circuit to modify the original output. You could use a microcontroller, but it might be pointless to just use it for that, as it could replace a lot of circuitry. You could convert PWM to analog and create new PWM from analog.

Comment: @Jessicasmith:  You changed the question after it was answered and you accepted the answer.  The answer to the new question is not the same as the answer to this question.  I know you posted a new question and were advised to delete it as a duplicate.  It wasn't.  The task is very different as is the solution.  Please undelete that deleted question.  If anyone gives you trouble over it, let one of the moderators have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could think of to preserve is by converting the input waveform to DC and generating the PWM signal form that DC waveform again.

The question is, how dynamic (what rate of change) the singnal must have.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZiMEB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a massively simplified shematic of a possible solution. You'd probably want a filter of higher order for the input signal. But what we're doing is basically via the R-C chain filtering the PWM input signal to get a somewhat stable DC voltage that's proportional to the input PWM (that's the "Filtered Signal). Than we use the comparator and a sawtooth generator to ceate a PWM signal of the desired frequency from the DC voltage.

Details depend on your use case.

Comment: Well, that's good enough. Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Comment: I like the "*venerating* the PWM signal"!

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica ouch... thank you, fixed the typo

Answer (score 2):

#### The short answer:

No, there is not.

#### The long answer:

This is technically possible, but far, far more complicated than you think, and you have to put some restrictions on the input waveform.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post to a square wave with 75% duty cycle, is it possible to reduce the frequency?

Comment: @jessicasmith Will it always be 75%? Will it always be the same amplitude? What range of frequencies will it have?

Comment: The input would be 1 kHz maximum, the output you can change it to any lower frequency less than 1 kHz that you like :). No, the duty cycle can change but the input duty cycle must be indentical to output. Yes, the amplitude will be the same

Comment: @jessicasmith All of this information should have been given in your question to begin with, rather than edited in after someone has already answered your question. This new restricted form is much easier (but still probably not as easy as you think) with a microcontroller.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Do you wanna try analog circuit, probably use LT Spice to simulate the results, then I will try to plug all the components on breadboard to test it out :)